# building multiarrays dynamically

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have trying to build a dynamic multiarray, my code is the next:

```
$stud_data=array('estudiante1','estudiante2','estudiante3');
  $dates_data=array('date1','date2','date3');
  $stud_datan=count($stud_data);

  for($i=0; $i<$stud_datan; $i++){
     $students[$i]['name']=$stud_data[$i];
     for ($j=0; $j<count($dates_data); $j++){
         $dates[$i][$j]=$stud_data[$j];
         $students[$i]['dates']=array($dates_data[$j]=>$i.$j);
     }
  }
```

When I `print_r $students, I report the next array:

```
 Array (
       [0] => Array ( 
                [name] => estudiante1 
                [dates] => Array ( 
                         [date3] => 02 
                         ) 
                     ) 
       [1] => Array (  
                [name] => estudiante2  
                [dates] => Array (
                         [date3] => 12 

                         )
                    ) 

            )
```

but I want to build this structure, an array like this:

```
Array (
       [0] => Array ( 
                [name] => estudiante1 
                [dates] => Array ( 
                      [date1] => 01 
                      [date2] => 02 
                      [date3] => 03
                        )
                      ) 
       [1] => Array ( 
                [name] => estudiante2 
                [dates] => Array ( 
                      [date1] => 10 
                      [date2] => 11 
                      [date3] => 12 
                        )
                       ) 
      )
```

What is my error?  Thanks for your help.  In the subarray dates only shows a value [date3] but not show [date1][date2]

Answer (score 3):

```
$stud_data=array('estudiante1','estudiante2','estudiante3');
  $dates_data=array('date1','date2','date3');
  $stud_datan=count($stud_data);

  for($i=0; $i<$stud_datan; $i++){
     $students[$i]['name']=$stud_data[$i];
     $students[$i]['dates'] = array();
     for ($j=0; $j < count($dates_data); $j++){
         $students[$i]['dates'][$j] = $stud_data[$j];
     }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  

Your code shows this:
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => estudiante1 [dates] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [date3] => 02 ) ) ) [1] => Array ( [name] => estudiante2 [dates] => Array ( [1] => Array ( [date3] => 12 ) ) ) [2] => Array ( [name] => estudiante3 [dates] => Array ( [2] => Array ( [date3] => 22 ) ) ) )

Comment: Thanks mattacular.  You idea is a good idea and I found the code:  $stud_data=array('estudiante1','estudiante2','estudiante3');
  $dates_data=array('date1','date2','date3');
  $stud_datan=count($stud_data);

  for($i=0; $i<$stud_datan; $i++){
     $students[$i]['name']=$stud_data[$i];
     $students[$i]['dates'] = array();
     for ($j=0; $j < count($dates_data); $j++){
         $students[$i]['dates'][$dates_data[$j]] = $i.$j;
     }
  }

Answer (score 0):

This is the array with the structure that I wanted.

```
$stud_data=array('estudiante1','estudiante2','estudiante3');
  $dates_data=array('date1','date2','date3');
  $stud_datan=count($stud_data);

  for($i=0; $i<$stud_datan; $i++){
     $students[$i]['name']=$stud_data[$i];
     $students[$i]['dates'] = array();
     for ($j=0; $j < count($dates_data); $j++){
         $students[$i]['dates'][$dates_data[$j]] = $i.$j;
     }
  }
```